# In ggplot2, how can I limit the range of geom_hline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Taking a simple plot from ggplot2 manual

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
p + geom_hline(yintercept=20)
```

I get a horizontal line at value 20, as advertised.

[image]

Is there a way to limit the range of this line on x axis, to let's say2 - 4 range?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment()` instead of `geom_hline()` and provide `x=` and `xend=` values you need.

```
p + geom_segment(aes(x = 2, xend = 4, y = 20, yend = 20))
```

Comment: @Dzidzis Thanks - worked. Will add +1 too, once my votes are back tomorrow!